# set DATE in query headers oracle sql (sql developer)

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to display specific data that will be using DATE in headers.

Data should be displayed in similar format to the shown below.

Master_Column|Todays_date|Today-1|Today-2|Today-3...

```
select  
   sysdate,
   SYSDATE "&&_DATE",
   (sysdate-1) "&&_DATE-1" --this header is incorrectly named
from 
  dual;
```

This however will not display the last header correctly.

Is there any way to set dates in headers that will change dynamically?

I need to have a range of 6 days. Each day as separate column.

Comment: In addition to the "format" for the headers, which you included, it would help to see an actual sample of headers. What should they look like? In any case, it is very unlikely that you will be able to make this whole thing dynamic, no matter how you try. (Short of writing PL/SQL code and running dynamic SQL, that is.) `&&_DATE` is always a string, not a date, so you can't subtract 1 from it.

Comment: True, good point string is a sting and you cannot use and date calculation. Dummy mistake. I just wanted to make header exactly the same as value of the sysdate. 
sysdate | sysdate -1 | sysdate -2 etc....

Comment: Again - you can't make header exactly the same as value of sysdate, because sysdate is a date, and header can only be string. Do you mean sysdate in some specific format? In what format? Would `2018-10-31` work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `_DATE` substituion variable is a string, which tracks your NLS_DATE_FORMAT:

```
show defines

DEFINE _DATE =  "2018-10-31" (CHAR)
```

You're sort of trying to subtract a number from a string; except you aren't even really doing that, because no calculation would be done inside the double-quotes anyway.

It's a bit messy but you could achieve the effect I think you are after using multiple substituion variables and the `column ... new_value ...` syntax supported by SQL Developer, with a query to set those values - which you can hide with `set termout off` (at least in recent versions):

```
column date_0 new_value date_0
column date_1 new_value date_1
column date_2 new_value date_2
-- ...

set termout off
select to_char(sysdate, 'YYYY-MM-DD') as date_0,
  to_char(sysdate - 1, 'YYYY-MM-DD') as date_1
  -- ...
from dual;
set termout on

set verify off

select  
   sysdate,
   SYSDATE "&date_0",
   (sysdate-1) "&date_1"
from 
  dual;

SYSDATE    2018-10-31 2018-10-30
---------- ---------- ----------
2018-10-31 2018-10-31 2018-10-30
```

However, you need to put the whole thing, or at least the 'hidden' part, into a file and then run that with `@file.sql`, as `termout` ins't honoured for statements run directly from the worksheet. ALternatively you could add `noprint` to the column definitions, which hides them too - but give syou extra blank lines in the output still.

You can also use those substituion variables to change the column formatting if you need to, e.g. with shorter dummy values selected:

```
column master_column format a20
column &date_0 format A10
column &date_1 format A15

select  
   'a' as master_column,
   'b' as "&date_0",
   'c' as "&date_1"
from 
  dual;

MASTER_COLUMN        2018-10-31 2018-10-30     
-------------------- ---------- ---------------
a                    b          c
```

Note that in the `column &date_0 ...` etc. clauses the variable names should not be enclosed in double quotes, unlike the aliases in the main query which do have to be quoted (because of the characters used in and the formatting of the alias name).

You can extend that approach further, and perhaps more neatly, by setting the column headers that way too; so the query itself doesn't have to worry about them:

```
column master_column format a20
column col2 format A10 heading &date_0
column col3 format A15 heading &date_1

select  
   'a' as master_column,
   'b' as col2,
   'c' as col3
from 
  dual;

MASTER_COLUMN        2018-10-31 2018-10-30     
-------------------- ---------- ---------------
a                    b          c
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I did tried your code, but every single time I am trying to execute the code I am requested to insert "Substitution Value for date_0".

Comment: Are you running as a script (F5) or as separate statements? It seems to work for me either way - at least as long as I've run the set-up parts at some point in the session. And I'm using version 18.3, it's possible an earlier version behaves differently...

Comment: I am on version 17.3 which may be quite old. it does happens each time I run the code either way F5 or just run the query. it is very interesting and very frustrating at the same time, that it works on one version, but not on another...

Comment: I know it may be another dummy question, but could you share full code that you are using as I may have missed something...

Comment: @A.Rosso - that is the full code I'm using. Version 17.3 isn't that old, and I've also just run this in 4.1 where it behaves the same. I'm not sure why you'd still be prompted if you copied and pasted the code... (If you edited your original code, maybe you have slightly mismatched names, but just a guess.)

Comment: found it... as we both were thinking I've something when updating script. due to this I was getting different results when pressing f5 and later run statement. Thanks a lot for this solution.